# Dividing a CMakeLists file into multiple projects

Tags: c++, cmake

I currently have a project which compiles using multiple dependencies like boost and protobuf. Now, protobuf .lib is created for static linkage (/MT). The boost .lib on the other hand is for dynamic linkage (/MD). I want the final output to exists for dynamic linkage.

As I try to build protobuf with /MD, the same causes LNK2038 errors. Hence, I decided to move protobuf to a separate project to build as /MT but output a /MD file.

Now the problem comes from my inability to do the above as I have yet to be initiated into the ways of CMake. I tried creating multiple projects in the same CMakeLists file, but that caused my cmake-gui's configuration to fail. So I tried dividing it into multiple files. I moved my .proto file to a different folder and created a CMakeLists file for it. The same starts with:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /MT")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /MTd")
```

Now I don't know how to link the output files generated to the previous CMakeLists project.

I was hoping for some advice on how to proceed.

Thanks

Edit 01:
Adding my CMakeLists.txt files:

1. Plugin CMakeList (Compiled in /MD switch):

> ```
> cmake_policy(SET CMP0043 OLD)  
> include_directories(
>     ~~~~~~~~Some paths~~~~~~~~~
>     )  
> add_subdirectory(protobuf_model)  
> include_directories(${Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIR})  
> set(<SRC_NAME>  
>    ~~~~Some file names~~~~~~
> )
>
> find_package(Qt5Widgets)  
> add_library(<plugin_name> MODULE ${SRC_NAME} $<TARGET_OBJECTS:protobuf_model>)  
>
> set_target_properties(<plugin_name> PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
>
> target_link_libraries(<plugin_name>  
>     ${MAIN_TARGET}  
>     ${QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY}  
>     ${QT_QTGUI_LIBRARY}  
>     ${OGRE_LIBRARIES}  
>     ${MyGUI_LIBRARY}  
>     ${QT_LIBRARIES}  
>     ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
>
> install_plugin(<plugin_name>)
> ```

2. Protobuf CMakeLists (I've tried compiling this in both /MT and /MD). Kindly note that protobuf.lib is compiled with /MT switch.

> ```
> set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /MT")
> set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /MTd") 
>
> find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
> set(PROTO_FILES
>     file.proto)
>
> protobuf_generate_cpp(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS ${PROTO_FILES})
> set_source_files_properties(${PROTO_SRCS} ${PROTO_HDRS} PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE)
> include_directories(${Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIR})
>
> add_library(protobuf_model OBJECT ${PROTO_SRCS} ${PROTO_HDRS})
> set_target_properties(protobuf_model PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
> #I tried adding this too: target_sources(protobuf_model INTERFACE ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES})
>
> if (MSVC AND USE_FLEXNET)
>   target_compile_definitions(protobuf_model PRIVATE _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING=0)
> endif ()
> ```

Edit 02: Adding error list:
[Error Report Link](https://pastebin.com/6ggukAmv)

Comment: I ended up creating a /MD file for the library in question as a hot-fix. Now to convince the upper management that using my .lib is a possible method.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create a master CMakeLists.txt in the root folder then use 'add_subdirectory' commands to add any subdirectories containing other CMakeLists.txt files. Then you can just use target names from one file in any of the others.

Comment: I did that and the same was added to my project. But, when I added the protobuf target to my add_library call, I started getting the same old lnk2038 errors. Thanks for the advice though. Much appreciated.

Comment: I think we'd really need to see your CMakeLists.txt files and the full errors to determine what is going on.

Comment: @Sean_Burton I've added the code. This has some recent changes I've tried. The error I am not getting is LNK2001(Unresolved external Symbol) and LNK2019(Unresolved External Dependecies).

Comment: Unless you include the full text of the error we can't even see which symbols it is having trouble linking...

Comment: Error report added to pastebin as it was kinda large. Link posted.

Comment: I'm not sure the issue has anything to do with dividing the CMakeLists.txt into several files, it seems to be a general compiler issue.